# MVC 4 Mobile Razor Views not being rendered when deployed on Windows 7 IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mobile, razor

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 4 website which has both desktop and mobile views. For example I have a desktop view named Home/Dashboard.cshtml. I then created a mobile layout view with the name Shared/_Layout.Mobile.cshtml and then added a mobile version of Dashboard view with the name Home/Dashboard.Mobile.cshtml.

I run the application from Visual Studio with IIS Express and tested the mobile version by overriding the user-agent from Google Chrome to iPhone and it works perfectly until I published and deployed the same application on IIS (verssion 7.5) of Win7, it doesn't rendered the mobile version of Dashboard view. What is strange here is that it does render the mobile version of Layout which is Shared/_Layout.Mobile.cshtml but not the rendering the mobile version of Dashboard which is Home/Dashboard.Mobile.cshtml.

Note that I also tested the IIS deployed version on Samsung Galaxy S (Android) but same result.

Why IIS is not rendering the mobile version. Anyone faced the same situation? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I figured it out. Build Action was somehow set to 'None' instead of 'Content' for Dashboard.Mobile.cshtml so it was not being published to IIS. My bad that I overlooked it.